# Create R Correlation Matrix with RevoScaleR package (multithreaded) functions in SQL Server

Tags: r, sql-server, sql-server-2016, correlation, microsoft-r

I am trying to create correlation matrix using SQL Server 2016 R Services.
Since that i will have large amount of data, i want to use the new Rx version of standard R "cor" function.

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/r-reference/revoscaler/rxcovcor) is the function that i want to use:

And this is the Code that i have right now.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #DummyData
CREATE TABLE #DummyData
(
     [VariableA] VARCHAR(24)
    ,[VariableB] VARCHAR(24)
    ,[Value] SMALLINT
)

INSERT INTO #DummyData([VariableA], [VariableB], [Value])
VALUES   ('A1','B1', 4)
        ,('A1','B2', 3)
        ,('A1','B3', 1)
        ,('A2','B1', 2)
        ,('A2','B2', 1)
        ,('A2','B3', 3)
        ,('A3','B1', 4)
        ,('A3','B2', 5)
        ,('A3','B3', 2);

EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script    
      @language = N'R'   
    , @script = N'
        library(reshape)
        pivotData <- cast(DataIn, VariableA ~ VariableB,fun.aggregate = max)
        curData <- cor(pivotData, method="spearman")

        DataOut <- data.frame(row=rownames(curData)[row(curData)[upper.tri(curData)]], 
        col=colnames(curData)[col(curData)[upper.tri(curData)]], 
        corr=curData[upper.tri(curData)])
    '   
    , @input_data_1 = N'SELECT [VariableA], [VariableB], [Value] FROM #DummyData'
    , @input_data_1_name  = N'DataIn'   
    , @output_data_1_name =  N'DataOut';
```

This code gives me the following result:

[image]

Any idea how can i achieve the same results, but using the MS RevoScaleR package?